# Why does the "boot>" prompt in OpenBSD disappear at startup?

Tags: boot, openbsd

I came home today to find my network unresponsive, and I have managed to narrow the culprit down to my OpenBSD 4.3 firewall.   I attempted to power cycle it, but now at boot time it hangs, and all I get is the basic banner message.

```
Using drive 0, partition 3.
Loading.....
probing: pc0 apm mem[639K 31M a20=on]
disk: hd0+
>> OpenBSD/i386 BOOT 2.10
boot>
```

The "boot> " prompt at the end automatically backspaces away after a few seconds.   Is that by design?   If not, what does it signify?   I have to maintain this machine so rarely that I have forgotten what normal behavior looks like.

Comment: Normal behavior is that it should pause for a few seconds to allow you to manually enter boot options, then continue booting. `boot>` shouldn't backspace away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem wound up being a faulty keyboard.    I switched out the keyboard and everything is working correctly again.  I have no idea why that would fix it, but it did.